# Why is globalization the mark of the beast?

Tags: eschatology, terminology, beast

Was listening to a sermon on K-WAVE from Calvary Chapel on the radio.

The pastor stated that "globalization" was a mark of the beast and that it signifies Jesus will be returning soon.

What's the biblical definition of globalization and why is it the mark of the beast?

Comment: Did he state that it was a *mark* of the beast, or a *sign* of the beast? I know that many dispensationalists believe there will be a single, one-world government under the beast. So they would see globalization as a sign that conditions are ripe for the beast to appear.

Comment: I'm assuming you were listening to David Hocking from Calvary Chapel. I looked at a few of his articles, and he does refer to a one-world government and one-world religion. Some believe that under the beast, there will be a unified government and a universal religion, both evil and opposed to the will of God. Hocking sees globalization as paving the way for them.

Comment: I have a hunch that the mark of the beast would be some sort of license that allows you to trade carbon credits (which in turn is what I believe will become the global currency). If you don't have this license, you won't be able to do business. It's not a theory I have, it's just a hunch.

Comment: Globalization is a 20th century term that has no parallel in scripture.

Answer (score 4):

Good questions I think we can glean two questions here

1. what is globalization and 2 - is it the mark of the beast

The Bible says

> "Then a third angel followed them, saying with a loud voice, “If
>   anyone worships the beast and his image, and receives his mark on his
>   forehead or on his hand, he himself shall also drink of the wine of
>   the wrath of God, which is poured out full strength into the cup of
>   His indignation. He shall be tormented with fire and brimstone in the
>   presence of the holy angels and in the presence of the Lamb."
>   Revelation 14:9-10

Here I think anyone can agree that if anyone receives this mark, whatever it is, they would be lost, for that is what the Bible says.  So based on what that pastor was saying if you receive globalization, you would be lost, eternally separated from God.  Based on Revelation 14:9-10 it is clear that whoever receives this mark would be separated from God, but that begs the question, what separates us from God, Biblically?  The Bible gives us the answer when it says

> "Behold, the Lord’s hand is not shortened, That it cannot save; Nor
>   His ear heavy, That it cannot hear. But your iniquities have separated
>   you from your God; And your sins have hidden His face from you, So
>   that He will not hear." (Isaiah 59:1-2)

There is one thing that separates us from God, sin.  Therefore to receive this mark of the beast must be a sin.  That begs the question what is sin as defined not by man but by the Bible?  The Bible gives us a definition when it says

> Whosoever committeth sin transgresseth also the law: for sin is the
>   transgression of the law. (1 John 3:4)

The mark of the beast, is something that separates us from God, it is a sin, and sin is defined as breaking one of God's ten commandments, which are still binding up Christians (see Matthew 5:17-20).  Is globalization itself a sin, that would earn us a spot in hell?  Perhaps more realistically what the pastor meant to say was that globalization is preparing the way for the mark of the beast for it is written

> He causes all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and slave, to
>   receive a mark on their right hand or on their foreheads,  and that no
>   one may buy or sell except one who has the mark or the name of the
>   beast, or the number of his name. (Revelation 13:16-17)

So there will be a worldwide commandment regarding worship, which breaks one of God's commandments that will be enforced using the economy (no buying or selling).  Do we know of a law like that now?  No.  But globalization is preparing the way for a law like that.  For a more in-depth study and to know exactly who the beast is and what is his mark may I recommend this great Christian website - http://www.666truth.org/ .  God bless!

---

Regarding your questions in the comments, it can be confusing because so many people break the 10 commandments constantly, but for those who love Jesus it should not be so for Jesus said "He who has My commandments and keeps them, it is he who loves Me. And he who loves Me will be loved by My Father, and I will love him and manifest Myself to him." (John 14:21)  In fact while we know that those who receive the mark of the beast break one of God's commandments during a time of economic persecution, right after the warning about the mark of the beast the next verse says

> "Here is the patience of the saints; here are those who keep the
>   commandments of God and the faith of Jesus." (Revelation 14:12)

This brings us hope, for while it will appear that the whole world will follow the beast, John saw a small class "who have the victory over the beast, over his image and over his mark and over the number of his name, standing on the sea of glass, having harps of God." (Revelation 15:2)  Could it be that John saw you?  You can be one of those individuals, redeemed and saved from sin by the power of the blood of Jesus Christ.  All the promises of the word of God are yours.

> "Whereby are given unto us exceeding great and precious promises: that
>   by these ye might be partakers of the divine nature, having escaped
>   the corruption that is in the world through lust." (2 Peter 1:4)

I have no hesitancy in telling you that in order to obtain the immortal inheritance and the eternal substance, you must be overcomers in this probationary life. Everything that blots and stains the soul must be removed, must be cleansed from the heart. We must know what it means to be a partaker of the divine nature, having escaped the corruptions that are in the world through lust. Are you willing to wage war against the lusts of the flesh? Are you ready to battle against the enemy of God and man? Satan is determined to enslave every soul if he can; for he is playing a desperate game to win the souls of men from Christ and eternal life. Will you permit him to steal from you the graces of the Spirit of God, and plant in you his own corrupt nature? or will you accept the great provision of salvation, and through the merits of the Infinite Sacrifice made in your behalf, become a partaker of the divine nature? God has given His only-begotten Son, that through His shame, suffering, and death, you might have glory, honor, and immortality.

Satan claims this world as his own, but Christ has redeemed it through His sacrifice.  Revelation 13 tells us that during the final crisis Satan will attempt to get every individual on the planet to break the commandments of God at the same time.  Some may ask which commandment would Satan attempt to force individuals to break?  The Bible gives us a clue when it says

> "If anyone worships the beast and his image" (Revelation 14:9)

Satan will give a counterfeit commandment regarding worship.  If you look at the 10 commandments, the first four commandments, thou shall have no other gods before me, no idols, do not take the name of the Lord in vain, remember the Sabbath day to keep it holy, these four commandments deal with worship.  The last six, honor your father and your mother, you shall not murder, commit adultery, steal, bear false witness and covet, these deal with our relationship between men. Therefore the mark of the beast must deal with one of the first four commandments.  There is much more to share, but I have to go to work at the moment, this resource has more information - http://www.666truth.org/history/666-and-the-mark.aspx

May the Lord bless you as you follow Him!

Comment: thanks for the info, very helpful. I am confused becuase many people break the 10 commandments consistently, so why does globalization circle back to these and if it does isn't it already happening?

Comment: Hi brother Greg good question, because I am limited on characters in the comment section I will add an additional answer to the bottom of my existing answer.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a little bit of conflation going on, but I believe the primary basis for the allegation to be Revelation 18, to wit:

> “Fallen, fallen is Babylon the great!
>      She has become a dwelling place for demons,
>   a haunt for every unclean spirit,
>       a haunt for every unclean bird,
>       a haunt for every unclean and detestable beast.
>   3 For all nations have drunk[a]
>       the wine of the passion of her sexual immorality,
>   and the kings of the earth have committed immorality with her,
>       and the merchants of the earth have grown rich from the power of her luxurious living.”

The judgement is given in verse 4:

> “Come out of her, my people,
>       lest you take part in her sins,
>   lest you share in her plagues;

And, a description of who and what she does continues throughout.  Specifically:

> As she glorified herself and lived in luxury,
>       so give her a like measure of torment and mourning, ... And the merchants of the earth weep and mourn for her, since no one buys their cargo anymore, 12 cargo of gold, silver, jewels, pearls, fine linen, purple cloth, silk, scarlet cloth, all kinds of scented wood, all kinds of articles of ivory, all kinds of articles of costly wood, bronze, iron and marble, 13 cinnamon, spice, incense, myrrh, frankincense, wine, oil, fine flour, wheat, cattle and sheep, horses and chariots, and slaves, that is, human souls. ... The merchants of these wares, who gained wealth from her, will stand far off, in fear of her torment, weeping and mourning aloud,... Alas, alas, for the great city
>       where all who had ships at sea
>       grew rich by her wealth!
>   For in a single hour she has been laid waste

What can be ascertained is this:

1. Babylon is loved by the "merchants of the earth"
2. Babylon is under the control of the beast, but is not the beast.
3. Babylon has been overthrown - therefore the international economic system has been overthrown

Typically, most dispensational readings of this text say that Revelation 18 shows the unholy alliance between "the beast" and the economic system of the age.  A linkage between the merchants who sailed the known world of the time and the merchants who run corporations all over the world is not a stretch. [David Hocking in particular makes this explicit here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rpd1GdWluKQ).

Given this conflation, it is a natural step to associate today's globalized mega-corporations who "grow rich on the sweat of the poor" with this Babylonian economy.  John's message to the poor of his day is very much in tune with the poor of this day - The rich are going to get their due!

Comment: but this is the basis of America, so now what?